# Does traffic from mobile applications to website improve website's Google ranking?

Tags: seo, mobile

There are many mobile applications (like messengers or e-health applications) that can send traffic to websites via advertisement. I wanted to know if this traffic can improve that website's rank (SEO)?

Answer (score 1):

Advertisement traffic shouldn't directly impact SEO. But it can have a ripple effect that does.

A user who clicks on an ad that directs them to your page might end up doing one of the following:

1. Linking to your page
2. Sharing your page
3. Telling someone about your site
4. Following you on social media

Any exposure to your website could have a positive SEO outcome as it is increasing your brand awareness. But in terms of the actual impact of the traffic sent to you from an ad, it shouldn't have much if any impact at all.

Google generally does not follow advertiser links or pass any link juice on them. And Google has set a webmaster guideline that states you should not be buying backlinks that pass value. So any ad networks that you advertise on shouldn't have a direct impact on SEO, but the ripple effect could.

Comment: That ripple effect exists, but it isn't cost effective.   In my experience I've only gotten a hundredth of a cent of SEO value per paid visitor.   If you had an extremely sticky site you might be able to get that up to a cent per paid visitor, but in that case viral marketing would probably work better for you anyway.

Comment: Yes, very true. It's hard to convert a visitor into a substantial ripple effect that pays dividends. But there are some sites and products that just have the "It" factor that go more and more viral with each visitor on the page. For most sites, this probably isn't the case of course.